# Using mouse-over on raster surface to stream values to text file using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3

This is a weird one. I have a user who wants to add a statistical surface to ArcMap and then **mouse-over the raster** surface and **stream those values** (z) **to a text file**. MouseTips can show underlying values, but I can't see a way to use it.

I'm not inclined to create features and geoprocess them for the results as the user wanted a real time experience. Several searches in stack and google have not yielded any results.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: What would be the next step in your user's workflow. I don't see how the results of this could be very meaningful, and there has to be a cleaner way to achieve whatever end goal they have.

Comment: Agree with @Tom, without further information on what they intend to do and what they mean by a "real time" experience it seems difficult to answer if you do not want to create features and geoprocess? Are you aware of the [pixel inspector tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/Using_the_Pixel_Inspector/009t00000097000000/), may be that is all they need?

Comment: Unfortunately the scientist did not want me to say what he planned to do with it. Lets say those values are picked up in real time, processed, and then visualised. I can think of ways by drawing a line feature class, then processing it. but.... Thank you Hornbydd for the pixel inspector tool. I did not know that was there. That will be very handy.

Comment: Look into [pythonaddins](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-tool.htm) for creating a custom tool that could react to click events and draw lines on the fly and whatnot.  Similar to PolyGeo's ArcObject suggestion, but with a lower barrier to entry (and generally more limited, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user is not processing the output file as the Z values come into it, I think the answer will be to use stream mode when adding a line to get the "real-time" capturing effect that your user is after.

Once you have the line, use its vertices (you may need to convert them to points first), to get cell values for them that you write to the text file.

Alternatively, I suspect that you would need to use ArcObjects to do more precisely what you describe.